# Generate AC PWM using DC PWM LM741

Tags: power-supply, voltage, power, circuit-analysis, current

[image]

Hi all, this is a LM 741 square wave generator. I want to modify it such that the dc input (PWM) (from 0V,5V) to correspond to the AC output (PWM) (from 5V,-5V). So, the dc input duty cycle should be the same as the output duty cycle of op-amp. How to modify this op-amp to do this task?

Thank you

Comment: Create a virtual earth at half the 5V rail. Use a single supply opamp like a LM358.

Comment: @Kartman. Thank you. If we use double supply (+ rail, - rail ), it would be troublesome right to control both rails with the same input PWM?

Comment: A voltage rail is meant to stay at a given voltage, its not meant to change with an input signal

Comment: Is it possible to ban the 741, somehow? Let it lie in books, or museums, only. Like pointing to a T-Rex with admiration (or not), but that's it, because it's no longer alive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you wanted to take the input PWM, turn it into an analog voltage (by a low pass RC filter), then turn that into PWM again (this can be done by [comparing the voltage to a generated triangle wave](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slau508/slau508.pdf?ts=1647500208301)), this would be only useful if you wanted to keep the duty cycle the same but change the frequency.

It will be so much easier to instead use an inverting amplifier to just change the voltage range. The gain needs to be -2 (0V,5V to -5V,+5V so double the range) and the non-inverting input voltage (Vref) needs to be 1.667V (calculated using the steps in https://www.ti.com/lit/an/sboa264a/sboa264a.pdf?ts=1647579746911 )

Comment: Right. Thanks for taking the time to answer my question :))